# Grouping table by multiple columns: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table with multiple columns that I am loading from a CSV file in R:

```
data <- read.table(file="test.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t",check.names=FALSE)
```

The data has the following format:

```
id    timestamp    quantity    zone
1         123          1        A
2         123          1        A
3         124          1        A
4         124          1        B
5         125          1        B
5         125          1        B
```

I am trying to get the total quantity of each entity based on timestamp and zone. In other words: how many items were there at given time and given place, so the result should look like this:

```
timestamp   zone   quantity
123          A        2
124          A        1
124          B        1
125          B        2
```

There are plenty of similar questions here on SO but I am always getting this `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'` error.

At the moment, I am trying to group only by one column, using the data.tables library but I just can't seem to be able to get it work.

Could you take a look on my script and tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

```
library(data.table)
frame <- read.table(file="test.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
DT <- data.table(frame)
DT[,sum(quantity), by = timestamp]
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: `DT[, .(quant = sum(quantity)), by = .(timestamp, zone)]`

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems that R cannot find my columns by name for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library dplyr as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(timestamp, zone) %>% summarise(quantity = sum(quantity))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(quantity~timestamp+zone, df, sum)
#      timestamp zone quantity
#1       123    A        2
#2       124    A        1
#3       124    B        1
#4       125    B        2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
 timestamp = c(123L, 
123L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 125L), quantity = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), zone = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")), .Names = c("id",
"timestamp", "quantity", "zone"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I get the following error when using this approach: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'quantity' not found

Comment: @Smajl Please check the output I got with the data.

Comment: Ok, it was a typo of one of the oclumn names. It works just like the other examples. Thanks